# Less stopped saving search history

Tags: search, storage, history, less

`less` used to save my search history to `$HOME/.lesshst`. A few days ago it stopped saving any new search patterns. I still see the old search patterns in `$HOME/.lesshst`, but the new ones are not saved there anymore.

I tried adding something to `.lesshst` manually. The added words became visible in less (hit `/` and then `UpArrow`). So, the `.lesshst` file is writable, but `less` itself cannot save patterns in there, perhaps.

What could be the issue? How to fix it?

This `less` is running in GitBash on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could identify the culprit and found a workaround. The issue is due to the mounted persistent drive in Azure, where my `$HOME` and `.lesshst` is located. This machine is a DevTest Lab VM.

Those Azure persistent disks, which survive VMs re-creation, has some major problems with file writing. It's not just `less`. Even `mv` in GitBash and simple writing to files from Java also have problems.

So, I relocated my `.lesshst` to a more robust storage (to a NAS drive) using `LESSHISTFILE` env variable.